# How do I add 2 conditional classes to a div?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is my div. What is the syntax for adding another conditional class?

```
.progress{ :class => list.overdue? ? "progress-danger" : ""  }
```

I essential want to add `list.dirty? ? "progress-warning" : ""`

But what is the right way to fit that in along side the list.overdue? part?

Comment: My suggestion is to use a gem such as [`css-class-string`](https://github.com/nLight/css-class-string) to do it cleanly. It avoids putting logic in the view and scales nicely when you have multiple conditional CSS classes. I [wrote an article](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/a-cleaner-way-to-set-multiple-conditional-css-classes-for-link-to.html?utm_source=stackoverflow) about how to use it. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you take it to a helper

View code

`.progress{ :class => check_list_over_due }`

Helper Code

```
def check_list_over_due
  if condition
    'classname'
  elsif condition
    'classname'
  else
    'classname'
  end
end
```

Comment: Good 'nuff, however it makes it difficult to know what classes could en up being used in that view (which is why I usually avoid helpers for that specific case).

Comment: Yes. That's correct but with the method you can pass parameters like `check_list_over_due(list)` which is equal to 2 answers here . And you can return a class from that method like `return "progress-danger" if condition` Is it?

Comment: Not sure I get your point. Your answer is fine/correct nontheless, it's a minor nit that you can't tell the possible classes from looking at the view code alone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's "right" per se, but this should work:

```
:class => [list.overdue? ? "progress-danger"  : nil,
           list.dirty?   ? "progress-warning" : nil].compact.join(" ")
```

Comment: Assuming it's HAML (looks like it is), you don't need the `join(" ")`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to write helper, like "progress_bar_class(list)" and implement all logic in light structurized code.